# when can you ask coding questions here?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I've noticed people asking questions related to shell coding, such as this user: [How to extract part of a string, in Windows batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/228794/how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-in-windows-batch-file) and was wondering when this is appropriate? I'm seeing some contradictions with "What topics can I ask here"

Comment: Basically "scripting" languages such as Windows batch files or bash scripts are on topic in many places. Batch files are considered to be a nearly "normal" use of computers and do not require "deep" programming knowledge. Same goes for Excel VBA. So long as you are not using massive custom functions then we accept the questions here.